# How to close flutter time picker using Navigator after successful http request?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using flutter `showTimePicker` function to show a time picker to user and the time picker should close and user should get navigated to another screen only after successful HTTP request. But I couldn't find a solution for this even in the documentation. I think the `builder` can be use to to this? But it's bit unclear how to use it for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be use   `Navigator.pop(context);`    for close TimePicker.